# How can I add an in-set border to my complex navigation element?

Tags: html, css

My navigation consists of many elements (including CSS hack triangles). Because of this, I have no idea how to add an in-set style border to it.

Basically, this is **what I have:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezR94.png

And this is **what I want (Designed in Photoshop):** https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1qKh.png

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="navbody">
        <div class="navheader">
            <a href="index.html" title="Home Page" style="text-decoration: none;color:inherit;"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
            <h1 class="GBHS"     >GBHS</h1>
            <h1 class="Athletics">ATHLETICS</h1></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#">House Points</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Results Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Participation Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign In / Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img class="runico" src="images/run.png">
        </div>
        <div class="triangles"><div class="triangle1"></div><div class="triangle2"></div></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav {
    width: 282px;
    float: left;
}

.navbody {
    background-color: #afa094;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 2px #202020;
    text-align: center;
}

.navheader {
    height: 130px;
} 

.logo {
    width: 70px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 22px;
}

.nav h1 {
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: left; 
    line-height: 26px;
}

.GBHS{color: #2f8168; padding-top: 10px;}.Athletics{color: #0b3d68;}

.nav-menu {
    width: 192px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;  
}

.nav-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.nav-menu li a {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    color: #102b42;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.runico {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.triangle1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 141px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 141px solid #afa094;
}

.triangle2 {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 141px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 141px solid #afa094;
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/JDzcP/  Don't worry about the images not being there, they still take up the space.

**ALSO** while I have the expertise of the stackoverflow community, how can I add a box shadow to the triangles?

Comment: Why not just use image backgrounds? This seems overly complex.

Comment: Or SVG perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/JDzcP/2/

Comment: The only way to do it with CSS that I can think of is positioning absolute div's on a relative parent layer, and rotating/skewing them to match your triangles, seeing the z-index behind the nav and doing a lot of trial and error. you'd be much better off doing the above recommendation with a *.png fallback. Too complex ends in terrible support in various browsers and pretty much restricts any kind of scale-ability.